# Add JSONObject to specific arrays

Tags: php, json

I fetch data in JSON format and want to order the objects I receive afterwards by putting them into the array corresponding to their ids.
The data I get has this format:

```
{
    "data": {
        "members": [
            {
                "groupId": "1",
                "name": "a"
            },         
            {
                "groupId": "2",
                "name": "b"
            },
            {
                "groupId": "2",
                "name": "c"
            },
            {
                "groupId": "1",
                "name": "d"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So I take the objects from the members array and try to put each of them into the array with the matching groupId which should look like this:

```
  {
        "1": [
                {
                  "groupId": "1",
                  "name": "a"
                },
                {
                   "groupId": "1",
                   "name": "d"
                }
        ],
        "2": [
                {
                  "groupId": "2",
                  "name": "b"
                },
                {
                   "groupId": "2",
                   "name": "c"
                }
        ]
}
```

I thought to achieve that by using a foreach loop and adding the objects into their arrays like this:

```
$json_data = file_get_contents('getfromFile.json');
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_data, true);

foreach($json_decoded['data']['members'] as $item) {
    
    $json_sorted[$item['groupId']] = $item;
    
}
```

But like this there is only one object added to the arrays. How do I add multiple objects correctly to a specific array?

Comment: Do you mean to add the data back into the `$json_decoded` array?

Comment: @NigelRen I‘m sorry that was a mistake! I tried to add it into a new array and that array only contains one object per array.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? https://3v4l.org/aoSJ5

Comment: @LukaszFormela for me it works when there is only one object for every groupId. If there are two objects with the same groupId they get replaced.

Comment: Can you give an example where there are two objects with the same groupid and what you want the result to look like.

Comment: It would help if you first extracted a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Now it's a discussion that revolves around your question showing things that don't represent the problem....

Comment: @NigelRen I added two more objects I hope it represents my problem a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my code.

If you should print last result as json you can use json_encode, or if you need to use array just use `$res` array as your final result

```php
<?php
$json = '{
    "data": {
        "members": [
            {
                "groupId": "1",
                "name": "a"
            },         
            {
                "groupId": "2",
                "name": "b"
            }
        ]
    }
}';

$obj = json_decode($json,true);

// Final result
$res = [];

foreach($obj['data']['members'] as $el){

    // Adding element to group array
    $res[$el['groupId']][] = $el;

}

echo json_encode($res);

//var_dump($res);
```

Comment: I didn‘t see you edited your answer, the first version did not work. Now with the edited version I was able to solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This can be solve your problem. If you have more of 1 item it return to collection or just one item :

```
$json_data = file_get_contents('getfromFile.json');
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_data, true);

$jsonDecodedCollection = [];
foreach($json_decoded['data']['members'] as $item) {
    if (isset($jsonDecodedCollection[$item['groupId']])) {
        $jsonDecodedCollection[$item['groupId']] = isset($jsonDecodedCollection[$item['groupId']][0]) ? array_push($jsonDecodedCollection[$item['groupId']], $item) : $jsonDecodedCollection[$item['groupId'] = array_merge([$jsonDecodedCollection[$item['groupId']], [$item]);
    } else {
        $jsonDecodedCollection[$item['groupId']] = $item;
    }

}

var_dump($jsonDecodedCollection);
```

Comment: Sorry for my change I can't notice I work on same array variable. I just create a new array and push the items to the new array.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your answer so far! With your suggestion I have a strange behavior: I tested it with four objects and my array contains the value '3' and the last object. Like this it doesn’t do a reliable job for me unfortunately

Comment: Hmm.. I though you want to collect in same array your items which are in same groupId. This codes check if an item is same groupId then the groupId turn to array.  In your case the array must be contains 3 item and one of them is array which exists same groups in an array.

Comment: I meant to want all items to be just inside the array. Like this it have a counter variable and one item of the four items actually represented in the array

Comment: Then you can be use just this: `$jsonDecodedCollection[] = $item;`

Comment: `$json_data = file_get_contents('getfromFile.json');
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_data, true);

$jsonDecodedCollection = [];
foreach($json_decoded['data']['members'] as $item) {
        $jsonDecodedCollection[] = $item;
}

var_dump($jsonDecodedCollection);
`

Comment: Then I just have a copy of the data I fetch